# Progressively growing cell-array class

Tags: list, matlab

I have written the following class to implement a "progressively growing" cell array in matlab:

```
classdef growinglist < handle 
    properties (GetAccess='private',SetAccess='private')
        inner_cells % inner pre-allocated cell array
    end
    properties (GetAccess='public',SetAccess='private')
        n_elements % current number of elements (index of last valid element in inner_cells)
    end
    methods
        %% constructor
        function self=growinglist(varargin)
            % you can pass the initial capacity of inner_cells to constructor
            if nargin == 1 
                self.inner_cells =cell(ceil(varargin{1}),1);
            else
                self.inner_cells =cell(4,1); % initial size is 4
            end
            self.n_elements = 0;
        end
        function add(self, element)
            % inner_cells is not enough, double it before adding
            if self.n_elements + 1 > size(self.inner_cells,1)
                n = floor(size(self.inner_cells,1) * 2) - size(self.inner_cells,1) + 1;
                self.inner_cells = [self.inner_cells; cell(n,1)];
            end
            self.n_elements = self.n_elements + 1;
            self.inner_cells{self.n_elements} = element;
        end
        function elements = get_elements(self)
            elements = self.inner_cells(1:self.n_elements,1);
        end
    end
end
```

However, it doesn't seem to be fast as expected.

In fact, performing these tests:

```
n = 30000;

%%%%%% concat everytime
tic
lst = {};
for i=1:n
    lst = [lst; 1:10];
end
disp('1 - concat everytime');
toc
%%%%%% exact pre-allocation
tic
lst = cell(n,1);
for i=1:n
    lst{i} = 1:10;
end
disp('2 - exact pre-allocation');
toc
%%%%%% "progressive" pre-allocation
tic
inner_cells = cell(4,1);
n_elements = 0;
for i=1:n
    if n_elements + 1 > size(inner_cells,1)
       n1 = floor(size(inner_cells,1) * 2) - size(inner_cells,1) + 1;
       inner_cells = [inner_cells; cell(n1,1)];
    end
    n_elements = n_elements+1;
    inner_cells{n_elements} = 1:10;
end
elements = inner_cells(1:n_elements,1);
disp('3 - "progressive" pre-allocation');
toc
%%%%%% using growing list class
tic
glst = growinglist();
for i=1:n
    glst.add(1:10);
end
elements = glst.get_elements();
disp('4 - using growing list class');
toc
%%%%%% using growing list class with exact allocation
tic
glst = growinglist(n);
for i=1:n
    glst.add(1:10);
end
elements = glst.get_elements();
disp('5 - use growing list class with exact allocation');
toc
```

I get the following results:

```
1 - concat everytime
Elapsed time is 4.954054 seconds.
2 - exact pre-allocation
Elapsed time is 0.006791 seconds.
3 - "progressive" pre-allocation
Elapsed time is 0.099431 seconds.
4 - using growing list class
Elapsed time is 11.618202 seconds.
5 - use growing list class with exact allocation
Elapsed time is 12.774726 seconds.
```

Actually, I expected the elapsed time of test n.4 and n.5 be much closer to test n.3.
but they're even slower than test n.1 (that I expected to be the worst). Furthermore, strangely enough, test n.5 is slower than n.4.

Maybe the inner_cells array is copied every time is set or some other copies are peformed, but I can't understand why, since I derived my class from handle class to support mutability.

I'm pretty new in matlab, so probably I'm missing something important...
any insight ?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.
I'm using MATLAB 2011a.

---

**EDIT :**

As suggested by 
@Edric, I used the profiler to find the bottleneck and I found out the culprit of the 
slowness is the `size(self.inner_cells,1)` function called inside the method `Add()` (**no idea why**).

Modifying the class in this way (to reduce size() calls):

```
classdef growinglist < handle 
    properties (GetAccess='private',SetAccess='private')
        inner_cells
        inner_cells_size
    end
    properties (GetAccess='public',SetAccess='private')
        n_elements % current number of elements (index of last valid element in inner_cells)
    end
    methods
        % constructor
        function self=growinglist(varargin)
            % you can pass the initial capacity of inner_cells to constructor
            if nargin == 1 
                self.inner_cells =cell(ceil(varargin{1}),1);
                self.inner_cells_size = ceil(varargin{1});
            else
                self.inner_cells =cell(4,1); % initial size is 4
                self.inner_cells_size = 4;
            end
            self.n_elements = 0;
        end
        function add(self, element)
            % inner_cells is not enough, double it before adding
            if self.n_elements + 1 > self.inner_cells_size
                n = floor(size(self.inner_cells,1) * 2) - size(self.inner_cells,1) + 1;
                self.inner_cells = [self.inner_cells; cell(n,1)];
                self.inner_cells_size = self.inner_cells_size + n;
            end
            self.n_elements = self.n_elements + 1;
            self.inner_cells{self.n_elements} = element;
        end
        function elements = get_elements(self)
            elements = self.inner_cells(1:self.n_elements,1);
        end
    end
end
```

Tests now yield:

```
1 - concat everytime
Elapsed time is 6.825776 seconds.
2 - exact pre-allocation
Elapsed time is 0.011783 seconds.
3 - "progressive" pre-allocation
Elapsed time is 0.088668 seconds.
4 - using growing list class
Elapsed time is 0.841975 seconds.
5 - use growing list class with exact allocation
Elapsed time is 0.818212 seconds.
```

That makes much more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the MATLAB object system is generally slow compared to built-in functionality - especially when you're running many thousands of method invocations each of which performs only trivial amounts of computation as you are in this case.

One thing that might help is to use the function-call style for method invocation (not sure if there's a better term for it). In any case, it looks like this:

```
add(glst, 1:10);
```

rather than

```
glst.add(1:10);
```

That allows MATLAB to realise straight away that you mean a method invocation rather than a field reference.

Comment: Oh... too bad... I suspected there must be some overhead, but I didn't think so big, in particular considering that MATLAB has a jit compiler. Thanks for the answer, I will accept it if none provides a more detailed explanation. (BTW I tried with function call style but basically nothing change)

Comment: By the way, just in case you haven't already, the MATLAB profiler might give you some indication as to where the time is being spent. MATLAB does have a JIT, but it cannot handle the entire language.

Comment: @Eric: it happened to be the `size()` function call inside `Add()` method (check my edit). I really don't know why, but now it's much faster...